# Have you seen this “exponent of matrices” before?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

No, not *that* matrix exponential.

Given an $n \times m$ matrix $A$ and an $n \times k$ matrix’s $B$ define their “funky exponent” $B^A$, an $m \times k$ matrix, entrywise by
$$(B^A)_{ij} := \prod_{z = 1}^n B_{zj}^{A_{zi}}$$

I hope I didn’t mess up the order of the indices here. Have you seen this matrix before, and if so could you point me to somewhere to read about it?

The funky exponent satisfies a few nice properties:

- $B^{A + C} = B^A \odot B^C$, where $\odot$ is the Hadamard entrywise product, and
- $(B \odot C)^A = B^A \odot C^A$, and
- $A^{BC} = (A^B)^C$.

I figured it might be called the “Hadamard exponent” on account of the first two properties, but I couldn’t find anything with that name.

Comment: Letting $f[M]$ denote the entrywise application of a function $f$ to a matrix $M$, then your funky exponent can be written as $B^A = \exp[A^\top\cdot \log[B]]$.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Have you seen this expression appear in the literature? Any interpretations of what it means?

Comment: No on both accounts.